# Returning save! value after code with DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save, dry

Hi I'm trying to write a code that is functionally equivalent to:

```
def model_method(args)
  ...
  obj.save!
  ... void code assuming save! worked ...
  return obj.save!
end
```

Normally I would use an after_save callback, however there are arguments passed into this model's method that I need to use for the `...code...` snipit.

Any ideas on how to do this utilizing DRY?

I was hoping something like `obj.save!.tap { ... }` would work but unfortunately not.

Comment: What are you trying to do actually?

Comment: Sorry I think I forgot to include that this was a model method. I'm trying to retain the truthy-return value of `obj.save!` after performing some code that would otherwise return `nil`. I would normally then do a after_save callback, however then I wouldn't have access to the `args` passed in.

Ultimately I just want to return `obj.save!` without having to write it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`save!` method will either return true or raise an exception, so you can safely do:

```
 def model_method(args)
  #...
  obj.save!
  #... void code assuming save! worked ...
  true
end
```

But this is almost most certainly wrong. Could you update your question so it is clear what are you actually trying to achieve?

EDIT:

For more general solution:

```
def model_method(args)
  #...
  if result = obj.save!
    #... void code assuming save! worked ...
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: Well to be more specific there is a customized callback that we invoke after the save! method. It looks similar to `obj.save!  <newline> invoke_callback(:callback_method_name, args) <newline> return obj.save!` Sorry I'm not sure how to not make that look ugly without new lines.

Comment: Do you want this callback to be executed every time you save the model. Use `after_save` method.

Comment: However in that case, I can't preserve the `args` that are passed in right? This way, I can manually set the args that are passed into `invoke_callback(...)`